# JDBC setObject with String type only

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working with JDBC template(SPRING) which wrraps JDBC. during runtime all my variables values (bind variables) are held as strings(with some recognition of their actual type: bigint\varchar etc.).
While I'm using setObject, I'm not sure if I need to cast the variable value to it's real type or I can send the variable as string to setObject and the database will convert it according to the column name in the database(i.e. if it is compared with BigInt then it will convert the string to big int and then query and etc.)

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Spring?

Comment: Currently 4.2. why does it matter?

Comment: Probably not, just want to make sure its not a very old version before I provide an answer.

Comment: On which class are you calling "setObject"?

Comment: Im not really using setObject, because i use SPRING API:
`public <T> T query(String sql,
                   Object[] args,
                   ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
            throws DataAccessException`

hope it makes sense

Comment: Did you run any sql to see if String bind variable is actually being converted to its corressponding db values ?

Comment: Here's an actual answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238912/3228998

At least "setObject(int, Object, java.sql.Types.OTHER)" works.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly then I think you CAN NOT use setObject to pass a String that will be converted to a non-String SQL type (int, bigint).

Look at [this question](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/alpine.BSO.2.00.1202081518350.29289@leary.csoft.net).  Below is the answer from that question.

> It is not the job of setObject to determine the correct conversion to the 
>   column type.  The setObject javadoc says, "The JDBC specification 
>   specifies a standard mapping from Java Object types to SQL types. The 
>   given argument will be converted to the corresponding SQL type before 
>   being sent to the database."  So it is solely looking at the Java type of 
>   the object passed to it and converting that to a SQL type.  So you pass it 
>   a String and it converts it to a varchar which is appropriate.  If you 
>   want setObject to do a conversion to a different type, that is the reason 
>   for the additional setObject variant which takes a target sql type to 
>   convert to, but that doesn't help your situation where you don't know what 
>   the target type is.